# Wrongly marked as duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

The question [Loading a stdout into a variable in a line using tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412659/loading-a-stdout-into-a-variable-in-a-line-using-tee) has been wrongly marked as a duplicate (by a gold tag user!)

The question the closer thinks it is a duplicate of is only about capturing stdout in a variable. This question is about capturing the output **plus** using it in another pipe

Could somebody with the privilege please vote to reopen it?

Comment: It is not *my* question. But I think it was wrongly closed. The question the closer thinks it is a duplicate of is only about capturing stdout in a variable. This question is about capturing the output plus using it in another pipe

Comment: Why not just comment on the question, notifying the gold badge holder, maybe he or she will do something themselves?

Comment: I already did. He insists that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: Well then I guess you have an impasse. Maybe edit it to clarify how it differs?

Comment: That's a possibility. But the user asking the question already did that. No reaction by the closer :(

Comment: "marked as duplicate" - the irony :)

Comment: @zoubida13 That's not the half of it. It's a question complaining that the supposed duplicate is no such thing marked as being a duplicate of a question which is no such thing. The people who mark questions as duplicates are so high and mighty, but they RARELY bother to find a question that actually is a duplicate and link to one that actually isn't. That is the case here. The supposed duplicate of this question is no such thing, because this question is about SOMEONE ELSE'S QUESTION, so the questioner cannot edit the original question because they have no power to do so.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I totally agree with you, I wasn't making fun of OP, just of the situation, no offense intended!